# My project does not compile on the wanted android version

Tags: java, android

I have `minSdkVersion` 14, but when I run on emulator of Android 16, the application starts but I can never connect. Same thing happens when I generate the APK to install it physically on a phone of the same level, often the APK does not even install. But yet, when I do the same test with an Android 6.0, the APK installs and works well. I am on this problem for more than a week and I begin to get discouraged, any help is welcome.

This is my build.gradel(Module: app):

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.a000webhostapp.elmitcha.constat"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

And My build.gradel(Project: DeclaConstat) :

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

        maven{
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything in logcat?

Comment: Title says my app does not compile but you are saying you can not connect.

Comment: Hello ! No no, nothing suspicious in the logcat "Henry", in fact I usually do my tests with an android level 25 where everything works very well but when I tried with a level 16 is I realized that it did not work on emulator or even on a real phone. And the problem is often that it is installed and I can not connect, or it does not even install. And "Olca Erlas" it's true I think my title does not really reflect my problem, I apologize. I hope that the little summary I made above will better understand my problem.